Change UV Map Transformation Orientation
I want to be able to change the transformation orientation on my UV map. I want to move it, but parallel to the UV edge.


Unfortunately, currently(version 4.1) there is no functionality like that in Blender. It could be a good feature request on Right Click Select

It's interesting that UV Editor lacks a lot of functionality regarding transformations compared to what is available in 3d viewports. Snapping is also very limited for example. I guess they are not that important for many users. It would be nice though.

Frustrating.. I don't really see any reason, in principle, a UV map shouldn't be first-class geometry, with all tools available, just in view-space? I would have thought that made for simpler implementation, too.. no need for a completely separate system.

But there is no reason some things like this would not be possible with Python(it even seems relatively easy) and we don't see any add-ons for it. Or am I missing something? Maybe I just don't know about it. I think people just don't really need those features... I mean I certainly don't absolutely need them. I want them though. It would be really cool to have everything as in 3d viewport.

I've just been playing with transferring  Position from UV-as-Geometry to the mapped object in Geometry Nodes.. works fine, and gives you all the tools, including Custom Orientation, not sure if it's a bit clunky to post as an answer. Only working as a Geometry attribute, so far.. I'm not writing into the UVMap. I just hope, eventually, Everything Nodes means Everything Attributes, so there's no need for 'Vertex Groups' or 'UV Maps' as separate subsystems.
